# I can't run my web3 app continuously in a loop

Tags: python, error-handling, request, web3py

```
p=web3.eth.contract(address='0xFFE811714ab35360b67eE195acE7C10D93f89D8C',abi=abi2)

while True:
avai=p.functions.claimsAvailable(address1).call()
realAvail=web3.fromWei(avai, 'ether')
balanaceDrip = q.functions.balanceOf(address1).call()
balanceDripReadable=web3.fromWei(balanaceDrip,'ether')
balance_wei=web3.eth.get_balance(address1)
balance=web3.fromWei(balance_wei,'ether')
nonce=web3.eth.getTransactionCount(address1)
print ('drip balance '+str(balanceDripReadable)+' current BNB balance is '+str(balance)+" Claims available "+ str(realAvail) +' listening, I will transfer your DRIP as soon as BNB enters. current nonce'+str(nonce))
```

This code is designed to run forever but after running for a while , it stops. It is not network as I am using a very powerful server with a very strong network. Here is the error below. How do I stop this error and run my code infinitely or how to do I restart the code automatically when this error occurs. Below is the error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\customers\cus2\dripTransferBot.py", line 26, in <module>
    avai=p.functions.claimsAvailable(address1).call()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\contract.py", line 957, in call
    return call_contract_function(
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\contract.py", line 1501, in call_contract_function
    return_data = web3.eth.call(
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\module.py", line 57, in caller
    result = w3.manager.request_blocking(method_str,
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\manager.py", line 197, in request_blocking
    response = self._make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\manager.py", line 150, in _make_request
    return request_func(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 94, in middleware
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\gas_price_strategy.py", line 90, in middleware
    return make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 94, in middleware
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\attrdict.py", line 33,
in middleware
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 94, in middleware
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 87, in middleware
    web3_formatters_builder(w3, method),
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\validation.py", line 142, in build_method_validators
    w3_chain_id = w3.eth.chain_id
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\eth.py", line 632, in chain_id
    return self._chain_id()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\module.py", line 57, in caller
    result = w3.manager.request_blocking(method_str,
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\manager.py", line 197, in request_blocking
    response = self._make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\manager.py", line 150, in _make_request
    return request_func(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 94, in middleware
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\gas_price_strategy.py", line 90, in middleware
    return make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 94, in middleware
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\attrdict.py", line 33,
in middleware
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 94, in middleware
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 94, in middleware
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 94, in middleware
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\buffered_gas_estimate.py", line 40, in middleware
    return make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\exception_retry_request.py", line 114, in middleware
    return make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\providers\rpc.py", line 88, in make_request
    raw_response = make_post_request(
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\request.py", line 103, in make_post_request
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 960, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/
```